# Avoid minify in react-native in release mode

Tags: react-native, minify, uglifyjs

I'm [Generating the release APK](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html) for Android and want to test it without minifying the code.

How can I generate a release version for Android or iOS without minify the code?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked `app/build.gradle` file for buildTypes?

Comment: I checked but seems nothing related with React-native bundle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the default react-native cli you just need to use *--minify false*.

e.g.

```
node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios  --minify false --dev false --reset-cache --bundle-output './ios/MobileTravelAdvisor/main.jsbundle' --assets-dest './ios'
```

Answer (score 1):

*[Haul](https://github.com/callstack-io/haul)* to the rescue,

Finally I found a solution, it seems that using Haul to generate the bundle is possible with the flag `--minify false`, use it with the command `haul bundle`

Comment: It's not possible to disable minification in production bundle.

Comment: Check  --minify https://github.com/callstack/haul/blob/master/docs/CLI%20Commands.md